# How to set the height of the body to avoid white spaces

Tags: html, css, height

I was having problems whit this for a while, and I know that some other people were too

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnqze.png)

**As you can see in the image, there is an excessive white empty space in the bottom of the page, it's because there was a component just there, but it was moved up with "position: relative;" and of course, the element moved up but it's still taking its original space at the bottom**

I was trying to define the height of the body, as well as to center the components and set a margin:auto; but it doesnt work

Any idea?? THANKS!

Comment: Does the element with the "hosting-plans have any `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` assigned to it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the code that illustrates the issue, that way people can maybe see/understand the problem without having to make lots of guesses on what "might" be wrong. Creating a minimal working example might even help you realise what the issue is yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

give your plans a margin at the bottom and you decrease the margin-bottom  to reach that space that you want for example:

```
.image-plans-hosting{

  margin-bottom: 200px;

}
```

You can use the inspector in your browser to find the values you like the most.